# how to confirm method runs asynchronous in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, adobe

I have a 3rd party method call im using for adobe analytics.  Anyway i want to confirm that one of the method calls runs on a seperate thread in android.  The docs say most of the calls do run asynchronous but i need to confirm this for the team.  Is there a easy way to do this ? Otherwise i'll have to wrap the call in a new thread and it might be spawning a thread twice which is more expensive.

For example, here is a call  im doing with adobe analytics. Im on the main thread but have a method that will do the call:

```
public void MainThread_TrackState(String pageName, HashMap<String, Object> cdata) {

        Analytics.trackState(PageName, cdata);

    }
```

how can i know if Analytics.trackState is asynchronous?

Comment: What is "one of the method calls"  Are you talking about library code calling your code?  Your code calling library code?  or library code calling library code?  `Thread.currentThread()` returns the Thread object that controls the calling thread.  If you did write (or can write)_ any of the code that is "supposed to run in a separate thread", then you can add a call to Thread.currentThread() to get the thread's identity.  Then you can test it to see whether it is a different Thread object from some other Thread.

Comment: my code will call a method in a jar file (so library code).   How can i call Thread.currentThread() inside of a method i have no access to ? i'll update my initial post.

Comment: If the library is supposed to create and use a thread, but it does not call (or can not be made to call) any code that you control in that thread, then I don't know what you can do to prove that it really does create and use a thread.  Maybe you can use a debugger to prove it, but that's an area where I don't have much experience.

Comment: In java you could probably install a security manager that forbids spawning of new threads - no idea if that API exists for android. That still doesn't help if the class uses a thread pool though, no idea there.